# How to print accuracy every epoch during the training process of CNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I don't know how could I evaluate the training accuracy and test accuracy every epoch in the following code? This CNN is used for MNIST classification and the code is copied from TensorFlow tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers.

It seems that it only records the loss for every epoch and I cannot find a way to add accuracy to the code. 
How could I do that?

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Dense Layer
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits Layer
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=10)
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
      onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
          labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
    mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
    train_data = mnist.train.images # Returns np.array
    train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
    eval_data = mnist.test.images # Returns np.array
    eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

    # Create the Estimator
    mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

    # Set up logging for predictions
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

    # Train the model
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": train_data},
        y=train_labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)
    mnist_classifier.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=20000,
        hooks=[logging_hook])

    # Evaluate the model and print results
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": eval_data},
        y=eval_labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)
    eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)

main(1)
```

Comment: What if you created an `accuracy` op in your `cnn_model_fn` and then added it to `tensors_to_log`?  As AWeston points out, calculating accuracy on the full test set every step could slow down training considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When training a neural network, it is common to train the model for many epochs. It may be preferable to print the accuracy after every n epochs, where you might set n based on the total epochs you plan to use. Personally, I prefer to log the data and view it in Tensorboard.